# SCNView not refreshing but after tap on screen

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I am stuck on a problem. I need to apply transformation (scale, rotation, position) right after i add model to my rootNode. Right after when i apply transformation on child model added to rootNode it shows fine on screen but when i apply transformation on rootNode it doesn't refresh. i experimented that as soon i touch screen UI updates. I also tried putting delay of 2,3 secs.
**expected**
UIView should update as soon i apply transformation to rootNode.

```
let res = SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: 0.5, z: 0, duration: 1))
                    //            let res = SCNAction.sequence([SCNAction.wait(duration: 2000), SCNAction.rotateTo(x: CGFloat(180), y: CGFloat(90),  z: CGFloat(0), duration: 1.0)])
                    self.rootNode.runAction(res)
```

i tried putting code in

```
RunLoop.main.perform {}
```

i tried using

```
scnView.preferredFramesPerSecond = 30
scnView.rendersContinuously = true
```

But none works. i am using sdk IOS 13.2. Any help please.

**Edit:**

```
var rootNode = SCNNode()
viewDidload(){
scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(rootNode)
....
}

    func initSceneWithModel(modelURL: URL) {
            
            do {
                try personModel = addModel(url: modelURL)
                menuButton.setImage(UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .bars, style: .solid, textColor: .white, size: XConstants.FONT_AWSOME_SIZE), for: .normal)
                selectedModel = personModel
                centerPivot(for: personModel!)
                moveNodeToCenter(node: personModel!)
                setupEyeBlocker()
                //        selectedModel = eyeBlocker
                updateFieldUI()
                
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                            self.applyInitTransformations()
                        }
            } catch let error {
                Utilities.xalert(inView: self.view, desc: error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        
        func applyInitTransformations() {
            if let info = vm.physicialFile.extraInfo {
    //            personModel?.position = info.person.position
    //            personModel?.scale = info.person.scale
    //            personModel?.eulerAngles = info.person.rotation
                
                var valueRotPos = SCNMatrix4Mult(SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(0,0,0,0), SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0,0,0))
                var valueScale = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(7.0,7.0,7.0) // scales to 0.1 of original size
                rootNode.transform = SCNMatrix4Mult(valueRotPos, valueScale)
                
                //            rootNode.position = info.root.position
                //            rootNode.scale = info.root.scale
                //            rootNode.eulerAngles = info.root.rotation
            }
            else {
                applyEyeBlockerDefaultPosition()
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: Have you check your camera ?

Comment: sorry. I didn't get the point. What do mean by check the camera.

Comment: Check if the camera has any constraint that would disable it to see changes. eg : If camera is subnode of root node, moving, or rotating the root node does not change what the camera is seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Apple clearly says:

...
**You should not modify the transform property of the root node.**
...
(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscene/1524029-rootnode)

This might be causing the issues you have with your scene. Avoid `SCNActions` to be run on the `rootNode`. They are designed to run on the content of the `rootNode` (any `SCNNode` added to the `rootNode`).

You could probably take a common `SCNNode`, call it like `myRootNode`, add it to the real `rootNode` and add all your other content to `myRootNode`. Transformations should then apply correctly to all your sub-content, if this is your goal.

BTW: `scnView.preferredFramesPerSecond = 30` never gave me more performence or any benefits. Leave it default. Scenekit switches automatically to lower framerates if required.

EDIT:
apply transformation like so:

```
// Precalculate the Rotation the Position and the Scale
var valueRotPos = SCNMatrix4Mult(SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(0,0,0,0), SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0,0,0))
var valueScale = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(0.1,0.1,0.1) // scales to 0.1 of original size
```

then you do:

```
myRootNode.transform = SCNMatrix4Mult(valueRotPos, valueScale)
```

(you could also try to use the `worldTransform` of the node or the other transform properties of the nodes `presentation` node-object)

Comment: Hi thank you for reply. Sorry for late replying. I tried like you mentioned creating a new node myRootNode and then add other to its child. Problem if apply transformation to any of children it work fine. like child.scale or chld.eulerAngle but when i apply to myRootNode.scale or myRootNode.eulerAngle it changes the value but not the children. But code work perfectly fine when transformation applied in gestures callback.

Comment: I updated my answer. Use whatever values you want. I am currently using the same construct for an animated character node and the transformations works perfectly for all child-nodes.

Comment: I edit my question with code. Can you please verify that myRootNode.transform effects children right after you child to rootNode and apply transform. In my code MyrootNode works fine later and effecting children but not as soon as i add. if i uncomment personModel?.eulerAngles = info.person.rotation then it works fine on UI. Thank you for all the help

Comment: Well, hard to tell at this point. Can you describe in detail, what happens between you add a model until it displays correctly? Does it like show in a different size as expected for a tic of a second, or whatever. I also consider to call your custom rootNode NOT rootNode, but any other name (like "myRootNode" or "mainNode"). Also make sure, that everything regarding UI components (ex: menuButton.setImage(UIImage. ...), when you change any value of it, always go trough the DispatchQueue. otherwise I'd have to look at your entire code. Good luck